# AnimatedVectorDrawable circle to line

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I want to realize an animation that transform a circle into a line in Android.

I saw this is possible with [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html) and I should use an objectanimator like so to make a path transformation:

```
<objectAnimator
     android:duration="3000"
     android:propertyName="pathData"
     android:valueFrom="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0   -70,70z"
     android:valueTo="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,0  0,140 -70,0 z"
     android:valueType="pathType"/>
```

And from the docs if one wants to morph a path into another one, **the paths must be compatible for morphing. In more details, the paths should have exact same length of commands , and exact same length of parameters for each commands.**

I've started to read this: [SVG elliptical arc commands](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands), I think the trick would be to realize a line with some arc/circle commands.

Is there a way to do this, so a line path data can have the same length and same commands as a circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iftah's answer put me on a good track, here is how I did it, it's basically approximating a circle with two cubic Bézier curves (one for the upper half circle and another one for the lower half). A small explanation can be found [here](http://digerati-illuminatus.blogspot.com/2008/05/approximating-semicircle-with-cubic.html).

Code side, here is how it looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="500dp"
    android:height="500dp"
    android:viewportWidth="500"
    android:viewportHeight="500">

<group>
    <path
        android:name="circle_line"
        android:fillColor="@android:color/black"
        android:strokeColor="@android:color/black"
        android:strokeWidth="5"
        android:pathData="@string/circle_data"/>
</group>
```

Paths data:

```
<!-- paths -->
<string name="circle_data">M 125 250 C 137.5 83.34 362.5 83.34 375 250 M 125 250 C 137.5 416.66 362.5 416.66 375 250</string>
<string name="line_data">M 50 250 C 125 250 125 250 250 250 M 250 250 C 375 250 375 250 450 250</string>
```

The animation works fine, I just have to refine some points in order to customize the animation look.

Comment: Can you explain how you did the animation?

Comment: I implemented it here: https://github.com/Tibolte/ElasticDownload
You should be able to find how it's done there (from the gif you see in the readme, it's the brown/black circle transforming into a line). If you have trouble figuring it out I can comment more on it below :)

Comment: Animating `trimPathStart` didn't work for me in vector drawable because of the multiple `M` commands. So I had to use a new path data which I kinda tinkered together based on this one, `android:pathData="M 62.5 127 C 68.75 41.67 180 41.67 187.5 125 183.5 208.33 63.5 208.33 63 123"`

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it, but I guess a simple "hack" that may work is to transform the circle into a circle with very large radius, centered far away. The small part of the huge circle that is visible in the clip area would appear to be a straight line.

ie. You can transform the circle from center (300,70) with radius 70 to center (300,10070) with radius 10000.

If that fails, you can try building a circle from splines and then changing the splines into straight lines. [This](http://mechanicalexpressions.com/explore/geometric-modeling/circle-spline.html) website shows a quarter circle made from a spline.

---

Another option that may work - animate the scaleY of the shape from 1 to 0, this will flatten the shape into a horizontal line. Its not quite as smooth as the vector animation, but its very simple to implement.  When the animation is complete you can replace the shape with a horizontal line.

Comment: nice! I tried here with your parameters: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_circle
I'll try to port that to Android

Comment: hmm android only accept path data I forgot, so I have to drop the circle command solution, looks like I have to work something out with splines.

Comment: what do you mean "android only accept path data I forgot" ?

Comment: In svg you can create a circle with a circle tag:
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
I was going to opt for that but according to the VectorDrawable docs we can only provide svg path data. That means that kind of svg data:
<path d="M300,200 h-150 a150,150 0 1,0 150,-150 z"
        fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" />
I'm afraid the tag circle cannot be translated into a vectordrawable, I've seen some docs creating circle with Bezier curves, mathematics here we come!

Comment: check here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html
I believe the only accepted tag is <path>.

Comment: I see... oh well. Another hack you can try is setting the scaleY from 1 to 0 - which will flatten the shape into a horizontal line. I'm editing my answer to include this option.